# NullPointerException When starting new Activity in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer, start-activity

I am using a template navigation drawer that was provided by android studio. I am very new to android development so i'm wondering if i'm missing something simple here. I want to start a new activity by clicking on an item in  my navigation menu I followed several tutorials on how to do this but i keep getting this error in my logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bsmyth.sidemenu/com.example.bsmyth.sidemenu.second_activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here is the code I tried to start a new activity:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } 

    else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, second_activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } 

      else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

I referred to my second activity in my manifest file like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".second_activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.bsmyth.sidemenu.second_activity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is the drawer layout:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Adfeed"
        android:checked="true"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Post" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Notification" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
        android:title="Messages" />
</group>
```

Here is the second activity:

```
package com.example.bsmyth.sidemenu;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class second_activity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is second_activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your in the second activity"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And here are the error messages in logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bsmyth.sidemenu/com.example.bsmyth.sidemenu.second_activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.bsmyth.sidemenu.second_activity.onCreate(second_activity.java:30)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: the problem is the second activity. post that code too.

Comment: check your second_activity onCreate() line 30

Comment: There is my second activity it is a copy of main activity apart for setContentView so that I could have the drawer nav on that page too

Comment: Are you sure there is `toolbar` in layout `second_activity` ?

Comment: not `toolbar`, make sure you have `drawer_layout` in `second_activity.xml` it is throwing `java.lang.NullPointerException` at `drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);`

Comment: There is no toolbar I will post my second activity layout now see what you think

Comment: please post your `second_activity.xml`

Comment: if you dont have widget with id drawer_layout in second_layout.xml how come you are accessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second activity layout has only a DrawerLayout and one TextView it does not have the views that you are calling in onCreate method.
Try running it again after removing this views from your onCreate:

```
   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)    findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
   navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: Thank you for that instead of removing them i added the elements from activity_main.xml (Used as layout for MainActivity) to second_activity.xml so that the second_activity.java which is a copy of MainActivity would find the same elements.

Answer (score 0):

add this:

```
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
```

to your `DrawerLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your in the second activity"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a little common sense on these, you are using `findViewById` for `drawer_layout`, `toolbar` as well as `nav_view` and other extras too.

But there is nothing in `second_activity` layout except one `TextView` even that is without any `id`. Then how can these codes work ?

Create these elements like shown in new android project in android studio then follow the same pattern and see how the next layout is included there.

Comment: Thank you I am very new to java and android development an was not fully aware of that id relationship between the java file and xml layout file

Answer (score 0):

Your will get multiple `NullPointerException` in your code. You only copied the code of `MainActivity.java` to `second_activity.java` but not in the layout file from `activity_main` to `second_activity`.

You can create your second activity in project explorer and selecting the activity you want from the template. It is the easiest way and also very good way. After that you can simply call the second activity from first activity like you are doing now

Answer (score 0):

You are doing many things wrong in second activity code....
In layout XML..you don't give any id for drawer layout which you are using (drawer_layout).
So Add this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Your in the second activity"
android:textSize="20sp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Also create this view **toolbar** and **nav_view** in this XML file like you have create Textview in second_activity XML .

And create Drawer object only once with same drwaer id(drawer_layout).
Like...

```
//declare this globally(means out of any method)
DrawerLayout drawer;
```

and then initialize this in onCreate method...

```
drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

and at last remove this line `DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);` from onBackPressed() and onNavigationItemSelected method.

Hope this will help you...